# Focus Traversable on CustomMenuItem. Content loose focus on mouse hover

Tags: java, javafx, focus

look at this simple app :

Press ctrl+space on the text field the listView appear with the focus and you can select with Arrow key. but if you move the mouse over the listView the customMenuItem got the hover highlight and the listview loose focus the Arrow key doesn't work anymore

How can i keep focus on the listview ??

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            HBox root = new HBox(new SuggestionTextFiedl());

`Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public class SuggestionTextFiedl extends TextField {

    ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>();
    CustomMenuItem lvContainer = new CustomMenuItem(lv);
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(lvContainer);

    public SuggestionTextFiedl() {
        super();
        List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
        content.add("item1");
        content.add("item2");
        content.add("item3");
        content.add("item1");
        content.add("item2");
        content.add("item3");

        lv.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(content));
        lv.setPrefWidth(100);
        lv.setPrefHeight(100);

        this.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {

            if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE) && e.isControlDown()) {
                System.out.println("ici");
                contextMenu.show(SuggestionTextFiedl.this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                lv.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }

}
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution not sure that is the right way

```
        contextMenu.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET, e -> {

            e.consume();

        });
```